# Create a dynamic truth table with few fixed variables

Tags: python, truthtable

I have an expression like below:
TXTXFX

I need to create different combinations by replacing X by "T" and "F". The expression might change based on the input.

I am using python to do it using lengthy for loops. (not yet achieved it)

Could you please suggest a convenient way to do it in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you ask, but

```
t='TXTXFX'

out=[]
for c in ["T","F"]:
  out.append(t.replace("X",c))
```

gives `out`:

```
['TTTTFT', 'TFTFFF']
```

Comment: I am sorry for not making it clear. The output for the above should be: [TFTFFF, TFTFFT, TFTTFF, TFTTFT, TTTFFF, TTTFFT, TTTTFF, TTTTFT]. I need all possible combinations for X.